# C# Parenting from Generic type of Generic type class? Too complex for me to form more fitting question to the problem :|

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have trouble with figuring out how can I use generic types to solve my problem.
Also I don't know how to describe my problem in short so I will make simplified version of my problem as extended exmplanation.

I am making system for switching quality, transitioning quality levels between different types of 'component' class.
I have base class like:

```
public abstract class QualityLevel_Base
{
    public bool Enabled = true;

    public virtual void Transition(QualityLevel_Base a, QualityLevel_Base b, double value)
    {
        if (value >= 1) Enabled = b.Enabled; else if (value <= 0) Enabled = a.Enabled;
    }

    protected static double Lerp(double a, double b, double t) { return (1 - t) * a + t * b; }
}
```

Then I inherit from it like:

```
public sealed class QualityLevel_LightSource : QualityLevel_Base
{
    public double Intensity;
    public double Range;
    public int ShadowsQuality;

    public override void Transition(QualityLevel_Base a, QualityLevel_Base b, double value)
    {
        QualityLevel_LightSource la = a as QualityLevel_LightSource; // One part of my problem - avoid casting
        QualityLevel_LightSource lb = b as QualityLevel_LightSource;

        base.Transition(a, b, value);
        Intensity = Lerp(la.Intensity, lb.Intensity, value);
        /* etc... */
    }
}
```

Then I want to manage quality levels in other class and be able to apply settings onto desired component class.
So I have base class to manage any count of quality levels:

```
public abstract class QualityManager_Base
{
    public Component SourceComponent { get; protected set; }
    public List<QualityLevel_Base> QualityLevels { get; protected set; }

    public virtual void Initialize(Component component, int qualityLevelsCount)
    {
        QualityLevels = new List<QualityLevel_Base>();
        SourceComponent = component;
        AutoQualitySettings(qualityLevelsCount);
    }

    public virtual void AutoQualitySettings(int qualityLevelsCount) { }

    public virtual void ApplyQualitySettings(QualityLevel_Base qualityLevel) 
    {
        SourceComponent.Enabled = qualityLevel.Enabled;
    }
}
```

And I inheriting it for LightSource like:

```
public sealed class QualityManager_LightSource : QualityManager_Base
{
    public LightSource Light { get; private set; }

    public override void Initialize(Component component, int qualityLevelsCount)
    {
        LightSource light = component as LightSource; // Another situation when I would like to avoid casting
        Light = light;
        base.Initialize(light, qualityLevelsCount);
    }

    public override void AutoQualitySettings(int qualityLevelsCount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < qualityLevelsCount; i++)
        {
            QualityLevel_LightSource lightSettings = new QualityLevel_LightSource();
            lightSettings.Intensity = Light.Intensity;
            lightSettings.Range = Light.Range;
            lightSettings.ShadowsQuality = i / qualityLevelsCount;
            if (i == qualityLevelsCount - 1) lightSettings.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    public override void ApplyQualitySettings(QualityLevel_Base qualityLevel)
    {
        base.ApplyQualitySettings(qualityLevel);

        // To my Question: I want to use generic type to avoid casting
        QualityLevel_LightSource lightSettings = qualityLevel as QualityLevel_LightSource; 

        Light.Intensity = lightSettings.Intensity;
        Light.Range = lightSettings.Range;
        Light.ShadowsQuality = lightSettings.ShadowsQuality;
    }
}
```

Actually I managed to use generic types on this problem making stuff like:

```
public abstract class QualityLevel_Base<T> where T : QualityLevel_Base<T> { /*...*/ }

public class QualityLevel_LightSource : QualityLevel_Base<QualityLevel_LightSource> { /*...*/ }

public abstract class QualityManager_Base
{
    public List<QualityLevel_Base> QualityLevels; // Would like to define it like that but I have to do it 
    // like that:
public abstract class QualityManager_Base<T> where T : QualityLevel_Base<T>
{
    public List<QualityLevel_Base<T>> QualityLevels;
}
```

Then doing something like this causes error:

```
public abstract class QualityManager_Base<T> where T : QualityLevel_Base<T>
{
    public List<QualityLevel_Base<T>> QualityLevels;

    public virtual void AddComponentForQualityManager(Component comp)
    {
        if (QualityLevels == null) QualityLevels = new List<QualityLevel_Base<T>>();

        LightSource light = comp as LightSource;
        if (light != null)
        {
            QualityManager_LightSource lightManager = new QualityManager_LightSource();
            QualityLevels.Add(lightManager); // Then I Can't do this because: "cannot convert from 'QualityManager_LightSource' to 'QualityLevel_Base<T>' "
        }

        /* ... */
    }
}
```

"cannot convert from 'QualityManager_LightSource' to 'QualityLevel_Base'"

There is of course more going on in my system, it is just very simplified version to define my question: How can I avoid casting classes, how can I do it correctly?
Thanks!

Comment: You created a monster that only you really understand, edit your question to clearly explain (in simple terms) what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: That’s not how generics work in C#. The parts where you ran into trouble is a job for OOP features like inheritance, virtual methods, and interfaces. Generics are not a replacement for any of that stuff.

Comment: How about making only needed methods as generic? I could mąkę use od something like (writing on phone): public virtual void <T> InterpolateBetween(T a, T b, transition) where T : QualityLevel_Base. Then I would need something like this on derived class: public override void <T> InterpolateBetween(T a, T b, transition) where T : QualityLevel_LightSource.   Or just changes type of arguments on overrided methods to derived ones, but don't knows if it's event allowed, will try search for it.

Comment: @Fyfyp One problem you have here is that `QualityLevel_Base<SubClassOfA>` is not a subclass of `QualityLevel_Base<A>`. If the type parameter `T` of `QualityLevel_Base<T>` can be an [`out` parameter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier), you can make that work: You can cast `List<String>` to `IEnumerable<Object>` because of the `out` in `IEnumerable<out T>`. But that's not magic; it's a promise to the compiler that the interface will only return items of type `T`, never consume them from outside, and the compiler will hold you to it.

Comment: I don't have a clear sense of how this will be used. I don't know what the `T` is for in `QualityLevel_Base<T>`. You should probably initialize `QualityLevel_LightSource` by giving it a constructor `public QualityLevel_LightSource(LightSource source)`. I don't know what the `QualityLevels` collection is for in `QualityManager_Base<T>`; I gather you want that to be a colleciton of `QualityLevel_Base<T>` with differing types for `T`. The answer to that is don't make it generic:

Comment: Define a non-generic base class `QualityLevel_Base`, have `QualityLevel_Base<T>` inherit from non-generic `QualityLevel_Base`, and make `QualityManager_Base` non-generic, with `public List<QualityLevel_Base> QualityLevels;`. Now you can put any QualityLevel implementation in that List. The next question: What are you doing with the items in that list?